# MySQL Multiple Aliased Joins Against Joined Table

Tags: mysql

I have this query, which works fine:

```
select table_1.*, coalesce(test_1.type) as type
from `tbl_1`
left join `table_2` on `table_1`.`table_1_id` = `table_1`.`id`
inner join `table_3` as `test_1` on `test_1`.`code` = `table_2`.`column` and `table_2`.`column` = 'L'
```

So, it's a query on table 1 with a join on table 2, then subsequent joins from multiple aliased joins of table 3 on table 2, but as soon as I add further joins, I get no results and I'm not sure why, for example:

```
select table_1.*, coalesce(test_1.type, test_2.type) as type
from `tbl_1`
left join `table_2` on `table_1`.`table_1_id` = `table_1`.`id`
inner join `table_3` as `test_1` on `test_1`.`code` = `table_2`.`column` and `table_2`.`column` = 'L'
inner join `table_3` as `test_2` on `test_2`.`code` = `table_2`.`column` and `table_2`.`column` = 'H'
```

Can anyone explain what I have done wrong?

Comment: Try `LEFT` join on `table_3` . If there are no records for `table_3`, that's why you yield no results, due to the `INNER` join. Actually, you're not joining any columns on `table_3`. Is most likely the issue.

Comment: ah, thank you! if you add that as an answer then I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `LEFT` join on `table_3` . If there are no records for `table_3`, that's why you yield no results, due to the `INNER` join.

And actually, you're not joining any columns on `table_3`. Is most likely the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What is the expected sample result of the second of your query ?
Could you please try this query ?

```
select table_1.*, coalesce(test_1.type) as type 
from `tbl_1` 
left join `table_2` on `table_1`.`table_1_id` = `table_1`.`id` 
inner join `table_3` as `test_1` on `test_1`.`code` = `table_2`.`column` and         
   (`table_2`.`column` = 'L' or `table_2`.`column` = 'H')
```

Comment: thanks, @WEI_DBA's answer was what I needed, I was using inner join instead of left join (was a mistake on my part in my laravel eloquent query which generates the raw sql), but I was trying to use the coalesce function to get a column value from another table (table 3), based on the column and value of a column in table 2.